# ESP32 freeRTOS u8g2 oled i2c -> i2c clock choice is invalid

Tags: c, esp32, freertos, u8glib

I am using the https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/tree/master/hardware/displays/U8G2 lib for an WROOM32 ESP32 Dev module.When I am scanning i2c I got this result:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 3c -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

When I am calling my OLED in the task, the ESP ist rebooting over and over again with this error in the terminal:

```
␛[0;32mI (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (0) u8g2_hal: sda_io_num 22␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (0) u8g2_hal: scl_io_num 19␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (10) u8g2_hal: clk_speed 1000000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (10) u8g2_hal: i2c_param_config 1␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (20) i2c: i2c_param_config(647): i2c clock choice is invalid, please check flag and frequency␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (30) err: esp_err_t = 258␛[0m
assertion "0 && "i2c_param_config(I2C_MASTER_NUM, &conf)"" failed: file "src/u8g2_esp32_hal.c", line 129, function: u8g2_esp32_i2c_byte_cb
```

This is my full code:

```
#include <driver/i2c.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include <u8g2.h>
#include <u8g2_esp32_hal.h>

#define SDA_PIN 22
#define SCL_PIN 19

static char tag[] = "i2cscanner";

void task_i2cscanner(void *ignore) {

    //The scanner works!
    ESP_LOGD(tag, ">> i2cScanner");
    i2c_config_t conf;
    conf.mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER;
    conf.sda_io_num = SDA_PIN;
    conf.scl_io_num = SCL_PIN;
    conf.sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE;
    conf.scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE;
    conf.master.clk_speed = 100000;
    i2c_param_config(I2C_NUM_0, &conf);

    i2c_driver_install(I2C_NUM_0, I2C_MODE_MASTER, 0, 0, 0);

    int i;
    esp_err_t espRc;
    printf("     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f\n");
    printf("00:         ");
    for (i=3; i< 0x78; i++) {
        i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
        i2c_master_start(cmd);
        i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (i << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, 1 /* expect ack */);
        i2c_master_stop(cmd);

        espRc = i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_NUM_0, cmd, 10/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        if (i%16 == 0) {
            printf("\n%.2x:", i);
        }
        if (espRc == 0) {
            printf(" %.2x", i);
        } else {
            printf(" --");
        }
        //ESP_LOGD(tag, "i=%d, rc=%d (0x%x)", i, espRc, espRc);
        i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
    }
    printf("\n");
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void task_test_SSD1306i2c(void *pvParameter)
{
    //The display does not work!
    u8g2_esp32_hal_t u8g2_esp32_hal = U8G2_ESP32_HAL_DEFAULT;
    u8g2_esp32_hal.sda = SDA_PIN;
    u8g2_esp32_hal.scl = SCL_PIN;
    u8g2_esp32_hal_init(u8g2_esp32_hal);

    u8g2_t u8g2; // a structure which will contain all the data for one display
    u8g2_Setup_ssd1306_i2c_128x32_univision_f(
        &u8g2,
        U8G2_R0,
        //u8x8_byte_sw_i2c,
        u8g2_esp32_i2c_byte_cb,
        u8g2_esp32_gpio_and_delay_cb); 

    u8x8_SetI2CAddress(&u8g2.u8x8, 0x3c);
    u8g2_InitDisplay(&u8g2); 
    u8g2_SetPowerSave(&u8g2, 0); 

    u8g2_ClearBuffer(&u8g2);
    u8g2_DrawBox(&u8g2, 0, 26, 80, 6);
    u8g2_DrawFrame(&u8g2, 0, 26, 100, 6);
    u8g2_SetFont(&u8g2, u8g2_font_ncenB14_tr);
    u8g2_DrawStr(&u8g2, 2, 17, "Hi nkolban!");
    u8g2_SendBuffer(&u8g2);
    printf("All done!");
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void app_main()
{
    ets_timer_init();
    //xTaskCreate(&task_i2cscanner, "task_i2cscanner", 4096, NULL, 10, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(&task_test_SSD1306i2c, "task_test_SSD1306i2c", 4096, NULL, 10, NULL);
}
```

Question: What am I doing wrong to use the display?

Answer (score 2):

In your u8g2_esp32_hal.c file after line 127:

```
        conf.master.clk_speed = I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ;
```

try adding the line:

```
        conf.master.clk_flags = 0;
```

I believe your issue is that the clk_flags are not being set

Comment: Hi, the error changed to: ␛[0;31mE (320) err: esp_err_t = -1␛[0m
assertion "0 && "i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_MASTER_NUM, handle_i2c, I2C_TIMEOUT_MS / portTICK_RATE_MS)"" failed: file "src/u8g2_esp32_hal.c", line 160, function: u8g2_esp32_i2c_byte_cb

Comment: That is saying that i2c_master_cmd_begin() on line 160 is returning -1 which indicates "ESP_FAIL Sending command error, slave hasn’t ACK the transfer." according to the documentation here https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2c.html#_CPPv420i2c_master_cmd_begin10i2c_port_t16i2c_cmd_handle_t10TickType_t

Comment: What screen are you using or the controller the screen uses? You may need to replace the call to:   u8g2_Setup_ssd1306_i2c_128x32_univision_f() with the setup call appropriate for your screen. You can find more here https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/u8g2setupc

Answer (score 1):

The library is out of date relative to newer releases of ESP IDF. The I2C configuration structure has received a new member `clk_flags` which this library doesn't set. See the details in [this thread](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=21030).

You can either drop back to an older release of ESP IDF (no idea which, sorry) or fix the U8G2 library (seems easy enough, check the [reference documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2c.html#configuration)).